# Toast não é exibido com a posição GPS

Tags: android

Eu estou desenvolvendo um app bem simples, quando o app é executado abre um TOAST com a minha posição GPS. O app esta executando normalmente, mas o TOAST não esta sendo exibido. Oque pode estar errado ?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pixelayer.masterpoint" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.teste.masterpoint;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements LocationListener {

    private LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                2000, 1, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        String msg = "New Latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + "New Longitude: " + location.getLongitude();

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Gps is turned off!! ",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Gps is turned on!! ",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: `LocationMananger` está ultrapassado. O recomendável é usar [FusedLocationProvider](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi) que é disponibilizado pelo `Play Services`.

Answer (score 1):

O *Toast* está dentro do método `onLocationChanged()`, tal como o seu nome indica só é chamado quando há uma alteração da sua localização.<sup>(1)</sup>
Enquanto não houver essa alteração, dentro dos limites definidos em `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 1, this);`, o método não é chamado.

Antes que tal aconteça pode, recorrendo ao método `locationManager .getLastKnownLocation()` obter a sua última localização conhecida.

No método `onCreate()` inclua o seguinte codigo:

```
if (locationManager != null) {
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (location != null) {
        String msg = "New Latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + "New Longitude: " + location.getLongitude();

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

<sup>(1)</sup><sub>É claro que este método também só será chamado se o GPS estiver ligado e com acesso aos satélites.</sub>

Comment: Apareceu o seguinte erro ( Cannot resolve symbol 'location' ).

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Comment: Eu fiz como mandou, mas continua não aparecendo o Toast.

Comment: Você adicionou a permissão para puder usar o GPS?

Comment: Meu manifest esta como eu coloquei aqui na pergunta.

Comment: Falta alguma permissão ?

Comment: Não. Não sei o que dizer mais. As razões para não mostrar o Toast são: `locationManager = null` ou `location = null`, veja qual delas é. Tem o GPS ligado?

Answer (score 0):

**Passo 1**: Já verificou se o `onLocationChanged()` está sendo chamado? Utilize Log para verificar isso:

```
Log.v("QualquerTAG", "Entrou no onLocationChanged() Latitude: "+location.getLatitude()+" | Longitude: "+location.getLongitude());
```

e verifique se ele foi chamado no console.

**Passo 2**: Caso o método esteja sendo chamado (passo 1), é provável que não esteja rodando na UI Thread. Então tente chamat o Toast dentro da UI Thread:

```
MainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

PS: Aconselho fortemente não utilizar `getBaseContext()` como contexto do `Toast`. Aconselho utilizar `MainActivity.this` ao invés.

**Passo 3**: Caso nada funcione, tente adicionar essas permissões e ver se o problema é resolvido:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```